# Getting Time out Error while executing hadoop jar ./hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar pi 2 5

Tags: hadoop

When I am trying hadoop jar ./hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar pi 2 5.It shows following error.

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3$ hadoop jar ./hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar pi 2 5
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 5
Wrote input for Map #0 
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
14/12/07 09:47:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 172.16.76.1/172.16.76.1:9002. Already tried 0 time(s).
14/12/07 09:47:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 172.16.76.1/172.16.76.1:9002. Already tried 1 time(s).
^C^Chduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3$ 


hduser@ubuntu:~/data/dfs$ jps
7176 DataNode
7484 JobTracker
6960 NameNode
7704 TaskTracker
7400 SecondaryNameNode
7766 Jps
hduser@ubuntu:~/data/dfs$ cd /usr/local/hadoop-1.0.3/

As you can see that all the processes are running.But when I go to log I found the below error;


ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/hduser/data/dfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

I checked my .xml files configuration.Which is as follows;

mapre-site.xml

<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>172.16.76.1:9002</value>
</property>

core-site.xml

 <property>
   <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://localhost:9001</value>
 </property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
   <value>/home/hduser/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
   <value>/home/hduser/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>    
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
```

I tried formatting the namenode and starting again.But nothing happened.
I changed my directory owner permission to 755 and tried again but still the issue did not 
resolve the issue.
I exhausted all the The suggestions given on this blog bur it did not help.
I though all the possible solution and tried so may times to solve it but still am not able to do 
that.The same issue is coming again and again.
Here is the detailed error msg:

```
2014-12-07 06:25:05,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory 

/home/hduser/data/dfs/namenode does not exist.
2014-12-07 06:25:05,377 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/hduser/data/dfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)
2014-12-07 06:25:05,399 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/hduser/data/dfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)
2014-12-07 06:25:05,407 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try delete the namenode storage directory /home/hduser/data/dfs/namenode and then format the namenode ?